# How to make ol.source.ImageWMS send POST request

Tags: openlayers-3

In our project, we're using OpenLayers-3's `ol.source.ImageWMS` to show image provided by Mapserver WMS. Since we're using Mapserver runtime substitution, our request can become quite long, which could cause a problem for a GET request.

Is there a way to make `ol.source.ImageWMS` send POST request?

Comment: No there isn't. ol.source.ImageWMS uses GET only.

Comment: I am having the same problem with get requests... :( Pls someone provide solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914173/how-to-add-a-http-header-to-openlayers3-requests, which shows how to use XMLHttpRequest to request images. You can use a POST method instead of GET there.

Comment: Have you ever got this to work? Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 6):

I answer this just for the reference based on this [Openlayers dev thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/openlayers-dev/imageLoadFunction%7Csort:date/openlayers-dev/39tX1fSeSc0/KGURE6NrexIJ), hopefully it will help someone in the future!. I needed to pass a very long CQL request to a Geoserver wms, and GET was limited in size, so I used POST like the following:

```
var POSTWMSLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'https://test.server.com/geoserver/wms',
      params: {
        'LAYERS': 'firstworkspace:states',
        'CQL_FILTER':'gid IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,2785,2786,2787,2788,2789,2790,2791,2792,2793,2794,2795,2796,2797,2798,2799,2800,2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807,2808,2809,2810,2811,2812,2813,2814,2815,2816,2817,2818,2819,2820,2821,2822,2823,2824,2825,2826,2827,2828,2829,2830,2831,2832,2833,2834,2835,2836,2837,2838,2839,2840,2841,2842,2843,2844,2845,2846,2847,2848,2849,2850,2851,2852,2853,2854,2855,2856,2857,2858,2859,2860,2861,2862,2863,2864,2865,2866,2867,2868,2869,2870,2871,2872,2873,2874,2875,2876,2877,2878,2879,2880,2881,2882,2883,2884,2885,2886,2887,2888,2889,2890,2891,2892,2893,2894,2895,2896,2897,2898,2899,2900,2901,2902,2903,2904,2905,2906,2907,2908,2909,2910,2911,2912,2913,2914,2915,2916,2917,2918,2919,2920,2921,2922,2923,2924,2925,2926,2927,2928,2929,2930,2931,2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942,2943,2944,2945,2946,2947,2948,2949,2950,2951,2952,2953,2954,2955,2956,2957,2958,2959,2960,2961,2962,2963,2964,2965,2966,2967,2968,2969,2970,2971,2972,2973,2974,2975,2976,2977,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,2983,2984,2985,2986,2987,2988,2989,2990,2991,2992,2993,2994,2995,2996,2997,2998,2999,3000,3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,3006,3007,3008,3009,3010,3011,3012,3013,3014,3015,3016,3017,3018,3019,3020,3021,3022,3023,3024,3025,3026,3027,3028,3029,3030,3031,3032,3033,3034,3035,3036,3037,3038,3039,3040,3041,3042,3043,3044,3045,3046,3047,3048,3049,3050,3051,3052,3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3073,3074,3075,3076,3077,3078,3079,3080,3081,3082,3083,3084,3085,3086,3087,3088,3089,3090,3091,3092,3093,3094,3095,3096,3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3102,3103,3104,3105,3106,3107,3108,3109,3110,3111,3112,3113,3114,3115,3116,3117,3118,3119,3120,3121,3122,3123,3124,3125,3126,3127,3128,3129,3130,3131,3132,3133,3134,3135,3136,3137,3138,3139,3140,3141,3142,3143,3144,3145,3146,3147,3148,3149,3150,3151,3152,3153,3154,3155,3156,3157,3158,3159)
      },
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
        var img = image.getImage();
        if (typeof window.btoa === 'function') {
          var urlArray = src.split("?");
          var url = urlArray[0];
          var params = urlArray[1];

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
              var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
              var i = uInt8Array.length;
              var binaryString = new Array(i);
              while (i--) {
                binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
              }
              var data = binaryString.join('');
              var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
              if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
                img.src = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
              }
            }
          };
          xhr.open('POST', url, true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
          xhr.send(params);
        } else {
          img.src = src;
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the httprequest is the problem, use Httprequest **Post** method instead of get method in ol.source.ImageWMS?

Get request can not pass long string parameters. For big parameters we need to pass request with post method.

Now the bottleneck is that the post method is not supported in openlayers 3 whereas in old version it had support for post method.

Note: This is old OpenLayers code

```
   var query = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.Post("My Layer",
        'http://192.168.6.51:8090/geoserver/VP/wms', {
            LAYERS : 'Namespace:LayerName',
            sld_body : strSld_body,
            format : 'image/jpeg',
            transparent : 'true'
        },
        {
            unsupportedBrowsers: [],
            isBaseLayer: false,
            yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
        } );
```

In openlayers 3 there may be a workaround.