# Openlayers 3: how to load a base64 image into a ImageStatic layer using imageLoadFunction() and how to access its content?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have access to a server that delivers base64 encoded satellite images. I would appreciate to see some real working example of how to do it using the imageLoadFunction(). According to the API docs in Openlayers v3.15.1 there is something like that

```
var extent = new ol.extent.applyTransform([-15.0,35.0,16.5,46.5],
                 ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857"))
var sst = new ol.layer.Image({
       source : new ol.source.ImageStatic({
             imageExtent : extent,
             imageSize : [2408, 1166],
             imageLoadFunction : function(image, src) {
                  image.getImage().src = src;
                },
            url :'myurl'
        })
    });

 map.addLayer(sst);
```

I don't understand how the image is loaded with the imageLoadFunction(). Is the src the output of the request ?. If I request the image directly through a browser I get a usual Json object

```
{"base64image":{"data":"image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg.....
```

So, should I write `image.getImage().src = 'data':src['data']` as I would do to insert the content into a '''' node ? and, how to access to the content of the layer once the layer is added to the map. I need it to change the color palette, etc.. of the image. Thank you in advance,

Comment: A very similar question was answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914173/how-to-add-a-http-header-to-openlayers3-requests.

Comment: Thanks I was unable to find such solution before. It solves the problem !