# How to add a http header to openlayers4 requests?

Tags: openlayers

some wms or wfs sources require user and password authentication. 
for example https://apps.sogelink.fr/maplink/public/wfs?request=GetCapabilities
need Basic authentication.
How can I inject this authentication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a http header to openlayers3 requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914173/how-to-add-a-http-header-to-openlayers3-requests)

Answer (score 5):

You can provide your own `imageLoadFunction` to an [ImageWMS source](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html).
The default one just takes the URL and inserts it as the src of the img tag:

```
ol.source.Image.defaultImageLoadFunction = function(image, src) {
  image.getImage().src = src;
};
```

That question was [already asked on the OpenLayers GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4213#issuecomment-145149625), here is an example from there:

```
function customLoader(tile, src) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', src);
  client.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar');
  client.onload = function() {
    var data = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.responseText));
    tile.getImage().src = data;
  };
  client.send();
}
```

The documentation of OpenLayers is *really* good. Just find an example that uses features you want and then follow the links to the API docs.The [ol.source.Vector](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) doc even includes an example of a loading function for WFS, where you could manipulate the request:

```
new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var wfsUrl = 'TODO';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // see above example....
  }
});
```

Comment: hello
It is very difficult to post comments, because the number of caracters are limited and the add comment box is very little.moreover I no longer have the possibility to enter formatted code. copy past sometimes removes line breaks. In short, I do not know how to do it easily.
I will try to split my comment.

Comment: I have already seen this answer but I do not know how to apply it here and then it only concerns wms, what about the wfs?

Comment: My try :
//image dict
var imagedict  =  new ol.layer.Image({
                      title: 'dict raster',
                      opacity: 1.0,
                      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                          url: 'https://apps.sogelink.fr/maplink/public/wms?request=GetCapabilities',
                          params: {FORMAT: 'image/png'},
                          imageLoadFunction: function customLoader(tile, src)

Comment: {
                              var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                              var user = 'sig@inrapdirmed.fr';
                              var pass = '#####';
                              client.open('GET', src);
                              //client.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar');
                              client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass));

Comment: client.onload(function() {
                                  var data = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.responseText)));
                                  tile.getImage().src = data;
                              });
                          client.send();
                      }
                  })
              });

Comment: and I got an error in console:

TypeError: client.onload is not a function

Comment: You are right, the syntax is wrong! it should be `client.onload = function(){}`. onload is not a function itself, but a place where we cann assign our callback to. I fixed the code, sorry about that.

Comment: ok, the header seems to work, but now I have the Cross-Origin Request blocking error. so I added "crossOrigin:'anonymous'" but it does not change anything

Comment: I think you should search for or open another question for "crossorigin XMLHttpRequest"