# OpenLayers Custom Tile Source URL

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've trawled through the docs and attempted some implementations, but haven't had much luck.

My tile URLs are basically randomly generated (8EBFU43L.jpg, for example) and the URLs are fetched from another non-standard API.

There are also multiple zoom levels (between 1 and 10).

Is it possible to use OpenLayers with this setup at all?

Thanks!

Comment: See this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105663/7635569) post

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the XYZ source shows you can pass a function that generates the URL to load a tile from:

```js
new ol.source.XYZ({
  tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) {
    return 'https://example.org/' + coordinate[0] + '/' + coordinate[1] + '/' + (-coordinate[2] - 1) + '.png';
  },
});
```

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html