# How to access with OpenLayers a private layer from Geoserver?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, geoserver

I can use the following code to show public layers, but if it demands authentication, I can't (as expected).

```
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    ratio: 1,
    url: 'http://url/geoserver/workspacename/wms',
    params: {
      'FORMAT': format,
      'VERSION': '1.1.1',
      STYLES: '',
      LAYERS: 'workspacename:layername'
    }
  })
});
```

How can I authenticate via OpenLayers request? There's any way to exhibit the private layers or if I want to use OpenLayers I must let all my layers open? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914173/how-to-add-a-http-header-to-openlayers3-requests expect with `ImageWMS` you use `imageLoadFunction` instead of `tileLoadFunction`.  It can also be specified directly in the `ol.source.ImageWMS()` constructor, there's no need to call `setImageLoadFunction()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding two solutions to this problem. One was point out by the [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254929/how-to-access-with-openlayers-a-private-layer-from-geoserver#comment95334391_54254929) in the comments and the other one I get it in the [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/ahaia2/how_to_access_with_openlayers_a_private_layer/).

Basically, in the first one, you have to change the imageLoadFunction to send in every requisition the username and the password in the header. There's a problem in this approach, though, the credentials will be available in the source code.

The other option is to deal with the Geoserver authentication in the server side.