# Using Leaflet with http post to send big wkt text to geoserver

Tags: post, leaflet, http-post, geoserver

Leaflet renders maps from geoserver based on http GET. But when sending over big values via viewparams, the url gets cut off and the call fails.

Need to submit a big value via viewparams to a geoserver layer

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GETMAP-POST-WITH-CQL-FILTER-PARAMETER-td3805482.html
The link above shows people have tried to tackle the issue, but it falls back to having to re-write leaflet entirely.
[How to make ol.source.ImageWMS send POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826627/how-to-make-ol-source-imagewms-send-post-request)
This link above talks about a method of rewriting open layer, but not leaflet.

Attempt to load a huge WKT String into your cql_filter of the url to a geoserver get map call and you will understand my dilema.

So after researching, does anyone have a solution to solving this issue? Perhaps there is a part of leaflet.js that we can tweak to make it send post request over to geoserver instead.

Comment: I fear that this is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you "need" to send big chunks of WKT for each map tile in the first place?

Comment: The idea is that a layer will provide me some buffer geojson, which i receive. Then i send it to multiple layers in geoserver as a wkt text as a view param value. This is to pass the geometry shape to the layer so I can do some buffering on the database side