# Can I force OpenLayers 5 to send POST request?

Tags: post, get, openlayers

Here is my issue.
I have to filter an ImageLayer with OpenLayers 5, so I prepared this kind of code :

```
const params = layerToFilter.getSource().getParams();
delete params.CQL_FILTER;
params.CQL_FILTER = myFilter;
layerToFilter.getSource().updateParams(params);
```

This code works fine, but not if "myFilter" variable is a too big string.
For example, with a filter like 'FEATUREID IN (1,2,3,4...1000)', I get a HTTP 414 URI too long.

My question is : is there a way to force OpenLayers 5 to use POST request instead of GET request when it tries to refresh map layers ?

I have some workaround ideas like building a smaller filter and prepare a view for this filter on database side, or by making preprocessing also on database side, but it will be really easier if I could simply send POST request.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated :-)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826627/how-to-make-ol-source-imagewms-send-post-request and after a quick test it looks like it works even if its for OpenLayers 3. But if someone has an idea to make POST request easier, or to make it automatic by any configuration inside OpenLayers, I take it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Geoserver can publish feature id as a property of a layer. So you dont have to use FEATUREID. You can use CQL_FILTER instead of FEATUREID

```
http://locahost:8080/?CQL_FILTER=id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Comment: Thank you @feyzullah, I know that I can use CQL_FILTER in many ways and with other properties. I put as sample "IN (1,2,3,4,5...1000)", but in the real use the id are random, not sequential, according to the filter apply on other data linked to the layer, so the filter is more like "IN (4,9,27,59,189,456,635...4568,9875,10256...)", and in most case, the IN clause is too big to stay in URL parameters.