# How use base64 image from POST WMS request with ImageMapType getTileUrl?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, wms

I want to use a very long CQL_FILTER on my WMS layer with google maps javascript. So, i found how to make a WMS POST request with OpenLayers (here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826627/how-to-make-ol-source-imagewms-send-post-request]).

I want to do the same with google maps api, so I am using ImageMapType and the function to do the POST request that I found. Using the function with the getTileUrl parameter, I thought that by returning the image with this function, like OpenLayers, ImageMapType displays the image on my map, but it doesn't.

Here is the code, do you know if I am wrong somewhere or if ImageMapType only accepts an URL from a geoserver and it is not able to read local URLs, such from base64. So is it possible to do a very long CQL_FILTER with the google maps api via a POST request or i have to use openlayers ?

Sincerly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>WMS and Google Maps</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var EXTENT = [-Math.PI * 6378137, Math.PI * 6378137];

        function xyzToBounds(x, y, z) {
            var tileSize = (EXTENT[1] * 2) / Math.pow(2, z);
            var minx = EXTENT[0] + x * tileSize;
            var maxx = EXTENT[0] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
            // remember y origin starts at top
            var miny = EXTENT[1] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
            var maxy = EXTENT[1] - y * tileSize;
            return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy];
        }

        var getTileUrl = function (coordinates, zoom) {
            src = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/demo/ows?" +
                "&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0" +
                "&LAYERS=demo:city" +
                "&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true" +
                "&BUFFER=40" +
                "&SRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256" +
                "&BBOX=" + xyzToBounds(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, zoom).join(",") +
                "&CQL_FILTER= Ville IN ('ST VULBAS','IZERNORE')"
            var img = new Image();
            if (typeof window.btoa === 'function') {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //console.log("src", src);
                //**GET ALL THE PARAMETERS OUT OF THE SOURCE URL**
                var dataEntries = src.split("&");
                var url;
                var params = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < dataEntries.length; i++) {
                    //console.log("dataEntries[i]", dataEntries[i]);
                    if (i === 0) {
                        url = dataEntries[i];
                    }
                    else {
                        params = params + "&" + dataEntries[i];
                    }
                }
                //console.log("params", params);
                xhr.open('POST', url, true);

                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        //console.log("this.response", this.response);
                        var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                        var i = uInt8Array.length;
                        var binaryString = new Array(i);
                        while (i--) {
                            binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
                        }
                        var data = binaryString.join('');
                        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
                        if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
                            img.src = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
                            img.width = img.height = 256;
                            console.log(img);
                            return img;
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send(params);
            } else {
                console.log(src);
                return src;
            }
        }

        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 6,
                center: { lat: 47.09, lng: 2.59 }
            });

            var overlay = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: getTileUrl,
                name: "City",
                minZoom: 0,
                maxZoom: 19,
                opacity: 1.0
            });
            map.overlayMapTypes.push(overlay);
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs.

```js
if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
  return 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
} else { 
  // handle error case 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already tried this but it not working, i have nothing on my map. Currently, i do that on an image, but i get the same thing (my image when i click on the link, but not on my map).
```
if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
     img.src = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
     img.width = img.height = 256;
    console.log(img);
    return img;
}
```

So, i think getTileUrl can read only WMS url, because when i set ``` if (! typeof window.btoa === 'function')``` in my script, i do a request with the url and i have my result on the map.